# How to interpret « ce qu’il peut y avoir d’exagéré » et « ce qu'il y a de meilleur »

Tags: sens

> 1 : L’expression « pour ainsi dire » s’emploie lorsqu’on veut affaiblir **ce qu’il peut y avoir d’exagéré** dans l’expression dont on se sert.
>
> 2 : La passion fait ressortir **ce qu'il y a de meilleur** en nous.

These two expressions have me puzzled. How do they compare with saying:

> 1+ : L’expression « pour ainsi dire » s’emploie lorsqu’on veut affaiblir **ce qui peut être exagéré** dans l’expression dont on se sert.
>
> 2+ : La passion fait ressortir **ce qui est le meilleur** en nous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's corrects things. 1+ is grammatically correct, but doesn't mean the same thing as 1, and 2+ is not correct at all. I'll start by the second one.

"*La passion fait ressortir ce qu'il y a de meilleur en nous*" feels very easy to translate : "*Passion brings out what's best in us*". It seems very close to me, can you see the similarity ? Literally it's "*The best there is* (in us)" or "*What there is best*".

The first sentence is based on the same principle, but with an "extra layer". I don't know if there is a equivalent in English, but you can break it down like this : First consider "*ce qu'il y a d’exagéré* en nous". It's the same construction, except the adjective is different. It doesn't have to be a superlative : "*Ce qu'il y a de bien avec cette bibliothèque, c'est qu'on est sûr d'avoir de la place*".

And then "*ce qu'il y a*" becomes "*ce qu'il peut y avoir*" to add a nuance, that could be translated by "can" or "might". There **might** be something exaggerated in the expression we're using.

Don't hesitate to ask me for more clarification, the post was already long so I didn't translate everything.

---

And for the disambiguation between 1 and 1+ : There is no way to tell the difference in English if I'm not mistaken, it's quite subtle :

1 is "**what could be exaggerated**" as in "*it might be exaggerated already, it's hard to tell*", while 1+ is "**what can be exaggerated**" but as in *it's not exaggerated yet, but is often subject to exaggeration* or *it's "exaggeratable"*. If the last part isn't clear don't worry, you won't encounter the second form. Again feel free to ask for clarification if need be.

Comment: Excellent explanation throughout. What's your take on the difference between 2 and 2+, now that I've corrected the typo in 2+? Merci.

Comment: Thank you ! Used like that, "*meilleur*" has the meaning of "*better*" and not "*best*", like in "*J'ai ajouté un peu de sel, c'est meilleur*". Considering the rest of the sentence, it doesn't really make sense tu use better. To mean "*best*" and not "*better*", you can also use "**le** meilleur" : "*Tu manges pas la peau du poulet ?? Mais c'est le meilleur !*" (*ce qu'il y a de meilleur* would also work there, but we have a shorter substitute, so the former works better for casual conversations).